# How to read a property on a static field in a spring-boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to convert the following code snippet using spring boot.

```
String message = propertiesService.getProperty("app.directory.errorcode." + errorNumber);
```

where `propertiesService` is used to read the `application.properties`.

**How do I read this in Spring boot as I have previously declared the properties 
using static keyword where class variables are declared ?**

```
@Value("${app.directory.errorcode.fatal}")
private static String fatalCode;
```

I need to generate the property name and read it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can achieve this using the class** `Environment` **from the package** `org.springframework.core.env`.

Example :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {

    // autowire the Environment
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private static String fatalCode; 

    public void someMethod(String errorNumber) {
      fatalCode = environment.getProperty("app.directory.errorcode." + errorNumber);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

}
```

I hope this may help you.

Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you Anish, I was able to do it with Environment property by following your suggestion. But I think this solution is standard for reading environment variables like URL and other, can I use it or is it a best practice to use it for reading application specific thing?

Comment: @SadiaH It depends. You can use it. There is no harm. Environment class is used when you want to read the values based on different properties. But this is the best solution as far according to me when it comes to dynamic property reading.